# XML file failing to append/save/update using powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, gpo

I have been trying to automate adding the shared printers on our network servers and add them to an XML file so then I can import the xml to GPO printer settings.

Here is the code I am using (test.csv contains 3 servers):

```
$shops = (Import-Csv C:\test.csv).Name
foreach ($shop in $shops)
    { 
        $Serverip = (Test-Connection -ComputerName $shop -count 1).IPV4Address.IPaddressToString
        $a,$b,$c,$d = $Serverip.split(".")

        $FilterMin = "$a.$b.$c.0"
        $FilterMax = "$a.$b.$c.254"


        $Server = (Get-Printer -ComputerName $shop | where {$_.PortName -like "10.1*" -and $_.Shared -like "True"}).ComputerName
        $Printer = (Get-Printer -ComputerName $shop | where {$_.PortName -like "10.1*" -and $_.Shared -like "True"}).Name
        $SharedP = "\\" + $server + "\" + $Printer

        $path = 'C:\Desktop\printers_test.xml'
        $xml = [xml](Get-Content $path)


        $CurrentDateTime = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        $uid = "{" + [System.Guid]::NewGuid().toString() + "}"


        $newPrinter = $xml.Printers.SharedPrinter.Clone()


        $newprinter.uid="$uid"
        $newPrinter.status="$Printer"
        $newPrinter.name="$printer"
        $newPrinter.changed="$CurrentDateTime"

    # XML Properties
        $newPrinter.Properties.default="1"
        $newprinter.Properties.path="$SharedP"
        $newPrinter.Properties.action="R"

    # XML Filters
        $newPrinter.Filters.FilterIpRange.max="$FilterMax"
        $newPrinter.Filters.FilterIpRange.min="$FilterMin"

        $xml.Printers.AppendChild($newPrinter)

        $xml.Save($path)


    }
```

Somehow, when running the loop I get the following errors:

> The property 'uid' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set.
>
> The property 'status' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set.
>
> The property 'name' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the
>   property exists and can be set.

It looks as if the settings from the XML file gets cleared during the loop.

Am I doing something wrong or missing steps?

Comment: At first glance: You have a collection of servernames in `$shops` and iterate over that with `foreach ($shop in $shops)`. However, inside that loop you continue to use the **`$shops`** array instead if the servername in **`$shop`**. Use better variable names to avoid simple typos like that.

Comment: corrected that, i forgot i was doing a test with a single server.

Comment: The results are the same... :(

Comment: Use `$newprinter.SetAttribute("uid", $uid)` instead of `$newprinter.uid="$uid"`. Same for the rest of the attributes